# ie8 not picking up background colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, less, joomla3.0

I've a Joomla3 website with a custom template looking fine in most browsers but awful in IE8. Lots of the elements just don't seem to be picking up background colours and are just white.

For instance the footer normally has a background colour. When I look at the template.css file (compiled from bootstrap and my custom template.less file) you can see the footer formatting

```
.footer  .container {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  background-color: rgba(245,248,250,0.7);
}
```

But when I use the website development tools of ie8 (via wine on my mac - in case that makes a difference) to examine why it is just white in ie8,  I see

[image: screenshot]

which seems to show that the background-color of .footer .container is just being ignored. 
Why would this be? Is this because it's compiled into a rgba format by the less compiler?

Many thanks for any help on this and how I might solve it.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 colors, such as `rgba()` are not supported by IE8, that's why it's not working.

You will have to take an alternative approach for specifying the `background-color` if you want support in IE8. If you don't mind losing the transparency, just use `background-color:rgb(245,248,250);` or.. `background-color: #F5F8FA;`

**See http://caniuse.com/css3-colors**

Comment: Thanks and that makes sense, but I thought the whole point of bootstrap was that their mixins etc. were meant to take care of this and put in whatever extra 'css code' to make it work?

Comment: @domc Unfortunately not.

Comment: So I've added a background-color to the CSS but it's still white. The .container2 includes the colour, but IE8 seems to be overwriting it to : none transparent …. with a class just called * as shown in   http://tinypic.com/r/2ebqskw/5   . Do you know why this would be happening and why it overrides the .container2 class css? Thx,

Comment: @domc You could remove the `*` declaration causing them to turn white.. or, since it's using `!important`, you would have to do the same.. for instance, declare `background-color: #F5F8FA!important`.. that would be required to overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for help and apologies if questions very basic as haven't had to deal with these ie8 issues before. The trouble with your solution 1 is I don't know where it's coming from, it's not from my template.css file - maybe it's hard coded into explorer, so not sure how to override it. And the problem with 2 is I'm trying to use Less so that I set up all the colours as variables and can then change them, and the !important doesn't seem to be compiled. I could always hardcode as you suggest. However would prefer a solution that didn't force me to hardcode, but maybe that's not possible?

Comment: @domc Unless you can remove it, you are going to have to hardcode it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is import css3.js in your website. This javascript files allows you to use CSS3 attributes that will work on older browser that wouldn't usually support it.

http://imsky.github.io/cssFx/

Once you've imported that, you can use the following as you were before:

```
background-color: rgba(245,248,250,0.7);
```

Just to be on the safe side, I think it's always good practice to have a fallback, just incase, like so:

```
background-color: #F5F8FA;
background-color: rgba(245,248,250,0.7);
```

Note that the fallback comes before `rgba()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue when using IE11 in enterprise mode.

I had this style set:

```
.heading {
            background-color:#f1f1ef;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:#E4E3DD;
            border-width:1px;
        }
```

and my table heading did not have the background color:

```
<th class="heading">Test</th>
```

I had to manually set a property bgcolor for this to work in Enterprise mode:

```
<th class="heading" bgcolor="#f1f1ef">Test</th>
```